# Log in to vtiger using vtwsclib.jar

Tags: java, android

I cannot get my android application to log in to the tiger database using the correct username and access key. I think it may be a problem with importing the vtwsclib.jar file into my project. Could someone help me out with this?

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.vtiger.vtwsclib.WSClient;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    WSClient client = new WSClient("http://en.vtiger.com/wip");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        boolean result = client.doLogin("talemany@timonhotel.com","EkMxqhEcBmXLaZx");

        if(result == false)
        {
            System.out.println("Login Failed");
            System.out.println(client.lastError());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Logged In");
        }


}
```

Comment: I do not get android studio to work with the vtwsclib.jar file. It says that It does not find the sources for it and so It says that the user is not logged in when I try to connect to the database using the doLogin() function.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

Its an example based on https://demo.vtiger.com/ for login

```
public class Login extends Activity {

      //URL to get JSON Array
      private static String url = "https://demo.vtiger.com/webservice.php?operation=getchallenge&username=admin";

      //JSON Node Names
      private static final String TAG_RESULT = "result";
      private static final String TAG_TOKEN = "token";

      // contacts JSONArray
      JSONArray contacts = null;

      String token = null;
      String sessionId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }


        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                   dialog.setMessage("Loging In... Please wait...");
                   dialog.show();
                  }

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            JSONObject result;

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                // Creating new JSON Parser
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // Getting JSON from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

                try {
                    // Getting JSON Array
                    result = json.getJSONObject(TAG_RESULT);
                      JSONObject json_result = json.getJSONObject(TAG_RESULT);

                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    token = json_result.getString(TAG_TOKEN);

                    //Importing TextView

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String username="admin";
                String accesskeyvalue = "w9OweWKUS4a5sSL";
                String accessKey=md5(token + accesskeyvalue);

                //For debugging purpose only
                //System.out.println(accesskeyvalue);
                //System.out.println(token);
                //System.out.println(accessKey);

        String data = null;

            try {
                data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8")
                        + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("accessKey", "UTF-8") + "="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(accessKey, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        String text = "";
        BufferedReader reader=null;
        //System.out.println(data);

        // Send data
        try
        {

            // Defined URL  where to send data
            URL url = new URL("https://demo.vtiger.com/webservice.php?operation=login");

         // Send POST data request
          URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
          conn.setDoOutput(true);
          OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
          wr.write( data );
          wr.flush();    

        // Get the server response    
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                   // Append server response in string
                   sb.append(line + "\n");
            }


            text = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {

                reader.close();
            }

            catch(Exception ex) {}
        }

        // Show response
        System.out.println(text);
        sessionId = text.substring(41, 62);
        //System.out.println("doInBackground()"+sessionId);



    return null;    
    }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);    
                dialog.dismiss();
               }

         }.execute();

    } 

    public String md5(String s) 
    {
    MessageDigest digest;
        try 
            {
                digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                digest.update(s.getBytes(),0,s.length());
                String hash = new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16);
                return hash;
            } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: **Replace variables as per your requirement**